# D3 Event Listener for Stream 'message' event

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, streaming

Good day everyone,

How is it possible to actually have a D3 element have a listener for an `EventSource` message event. The event is triggered by the HTML5 Streaming Event as described in [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/) article.

The Following is the event source:

```
...
# generate event source
if (!!window.EventSource)
source = new EventSource('/stream?hashtags='+gon.hashtags)

# Add event listener to stream source
source.addEventListener('message',(e) -> ??? , false)
...
```

The element that has a listener (different namespace, different file):

```
# Create a square canvas with width equal to the div's width
svg = d3.select('#d3-canvas').append('svg')
.attr(
  width: w
  height: h
)
.on('message', () -> alert 'test')
.attr('id','d3-svg')
```

I want to have a D3 Layout listening and updating on new message with data send by the HTML5 stream.

Any help maybe?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You would need to put the code that updates the visualisation in the `message` handler function.

Comment: But then I need to have all references reassigned by using d3.select('svg') correct?

Comment: Not necessarily if the handler function is part of a closure that defines `svg`.